# How can I keep track of comments I have reported on YouTube?

Tags: youtube

Sometimes, when I see exceptionally violent or hateful comments on YouTube, I report them has violent or harassing.

I've often wondered if there's a way to keep track of these reports, to see if the violent comments were actually removed or not. Sort of like the the list of submitted flags on SE.

I could obviously manually keep a list of these comments, but it would be tedious to find them all again.

Answer (score 1):

YouTube does have a list of flagged *videos* for certain users (the Trusted Flaggers-branch of YouTube Heroes), but they don't keep one for flagged comments, no. Half a decade ago, in the old comment system, they used to e-mail you the result, but this doesn't happen anymore.